# What value of 'a' will be the function is convex, concave or not either?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

$$f(x,y) = -6x^2 + (2a+4)xy - y^2 + 4ay$$

The solution has to be :

$$-2-\text{gyök}(6) \leq a \leq -2 + \text{gyök}(6)$$

I tried to define the derivation of the function accordance with $x$ , and after that $y$ , but I don't know how to derivate the function because of the $(2a+4)$, thus I don't know define the solution, as well.

Comment: what is "gyök" ?

Comment: in English maybe it is the root.

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt 6$ ?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left((2a+4)xy\right)=(2a+4)y$ ? Where is your problem?

Comment: Yes, I mean √6. It's okay. But when I do the derivations, I have already got the values, but after that and I don't know how to get the value of a.

Comment: Do you know the conditions for convex or concave functions? If so, write them down.

Comment: If f ''(x) >0 the function is convex. And if f ''(x) <0 the function is concave.

Comment: It's right, isn't it?

Comment: And when you have to variables $x$ and $y$?